# ionic ios package build failed - "cannot find module '../cordova/platform metadata' "

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Got error message "ionic failed to restore plugin from config.xml Cannot find module '../cordova/platform_metadata'" when building .ipa file.

All plugins are updated, tried downgrade to Cordova 7.1.0, doesn't work.

Only happened to ios, Android builds fine.

Here is the ionic info 
Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.1.1

Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

Cordova Platforms     : android 6.3.0, ios 4.5.4

Cordova Plugins       : not available

System:

NodeJS : v6.11.5 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)

npm    : 2.15.12

OS     : Windows 10

Could anybody help?

Comment: the actual same thing happens to me. Are you solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
ionic cordova platforms rm ios
ionic cordova plugins rm cordova-plugin-swift-support
ionic cordova plugins add cordova-plugin-add-swift-support
ionic cordova platforms add ios
```

This should help you and solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you Kai, I just tried exactly same commands like 30 mins ago, unfortunately, it didn't work for me:(

Comment: Triend but didnot help